# Computer cannot recognize USB with ubuntu

Tags: grub2, system-installation, usb

Yo. I'm trying to install ubuntu on my computer which is having troubles. Wenever I turn on the computer, it runs GRUB in rescue-mode, and says that every partition has an "unknown filesystem". There are five entries to a "ls" command. "(hd0 (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1). I've tried messing with the boot-order, boot-menu, and setting the boot device to USB-HDD, but none of that works. In GRUB, it doesn't matter which USB port I plug the flashdrive into, it always has the same five entries.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Yo, sure, lots. Go into BIOS and be SUPER-SURE that you're really booting the USB instead of some whatever from a failed earlier attempt to install. If you are super-sure that it's the USB hassling you, then re-make the USB. That kind of symptom happens to some folks on subsequent attempts to install after a botched first try.

Comment: Thank you so much, will do :) I should be booting to USB-HDD, right?